# Closed $n$ cell and Hausdorff property proof

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Problem: Assume $Y$ is Hausdorff and $E$ is a closed $n$ cell in $Y$ where $n>0$. If $\Phi: D^n\rightarrow E$ is a homeomorphism then $\Phi(D^n\backslash \mathbb{S}^{n-1})$ is an open $n$ cell in $Y$ with closure $E$.

My attempt:

Note that $\overline{D\backslash \mathbb{S}^{n-1}}=D^n$. Hence,

As $\Phi$ is a homeomorphism,  $\overline{\Phi(D^n\backslash \mathbb{S}^{n-1}})=\Phi(\overline{D^n\backslash \mathbb{S}^{n-1}})=\Phi(D^n)=E$. Note that $\Phi$ is a homeomorphism and so restricting to $D^n\backslash \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ we get a homeomorphism onto its image.

Why is the Hausdorff property required?

Comment: What is $\Phi(D^n\backslash E)$? And what is the definition of a closed cell? Just the image of $\Phi$?

Comment: @PaulFrost a closed cell is a space homeomorphic to $D^n$

Answer (score 1):

If $Y$ is not Hausdorff, then there is no reason to expect that $\overline{\Phi(D^n\backslash \mathbb{S}^{n-1}})=\Phi(\overline{D^n\backslash \mathbb{S}^{n-1}})$ in $Y$. It is only correct for the closure in the subspace $E$. Example:

Let $Y = D^n + S$, where $S$ is any non-empty set. Give $Y$ the topology consisting of all open subsets of $D^n$ and $Y$ itself.